# How can I create a Dot and Column chart in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

How can I combine a Dot chart with multiple data points and layer these data points on-top of plotted columns in PowerBi? Essentially, Dot and Column combo chart. I've tried a Dot chart app and R script without success. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Deneb](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/coacervolimited1596856650797.deneb?tab=overview) and then pick one of the [examples](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/) from Vega or Vega-Lite as a starting point.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think there is a solution embedded within what you suggest. Ultimately, I used a Box and Whisker chart to plot what I needed since it was a more straightforward solution with less of a learning curve. Thank you!